# Vue late model initialization

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Say I have the following input I want to bind to a model which doesn't exist yet

```
<input type="number" v-model="emptyObject.model"/>
```

The `emptyObject: {}` exists in `data` before the Vue instance is created, however it's empty. The model `emptyObject.model` gets added into the object in some method as a result of a user action (click, for example). The problem is that the model is not reactive if it's added late. I noticed that it only gets reactive if I add it to `emptyObject` before the Vue instance is created. Is it impossible in Vue to bind whatever to models which are not in the `data` object yet? Angular can handle it so I thought Vue too.

Comment: Not sure, but I think you are looking for `Vue.set` https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on [Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

If you aren't going to specify every reactive property upfront in the [`data`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) object, then you need to use [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) to add the property at a later time.